# Would it make sense to have a separate Scala library in Android market?

Tags: android, scala, bundle, google-play

As far as I understand it is necessary for people using Scala for Android applications to bundle the Scala classes they used with their application.

Considering this adds hundreds of kilobytes to each Scala app redundantly, would it be possible to build a Scala library which can be delivered over the market, so app writers can just depend on that library instead of bundling it themselves?

Comment: Indeed, I didn't quite understand what you meant. You mean like the dreaded Visual C++ runtime, right? Yes, I saw similar things on Symbian, and I thought the idea was reasonable. I'll retract my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third party shared libraries are not currently supported.  They can introduce a lot of issues that then end up being visible to the user (see: DLL hell), so in many cases the disadvantages of a traditional shared library model may out-weight the benefits.

Answer (score 2):

You'd probably be better off using something like [Proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/). See [here](http://chneukirchen.org/blog/archive/2009/04/programming-for-android-with-scala.html) for someone's instructions on how to do this.

Comment: I know that at the moment the recommended way to make the apps smaller is to produce a package with all unused classes stripped out, but that wasn't my question. Even under these circumstances the question is valid: Why not provide a shared basic subset of the Scala library then?

Answer (score 0):

If you need well-grounded maven project for Android with Scala, [android-scala-test](https://github.com/rohansingh/android-scala-test) would help you. It provides all of the complex setup out-of-the-box, including Scala compiler, Proguard, Signing, etc.

Further, [android-scala-common](https://github.com/pocorall/android-scala-common) will guide you to write more concise Android program in Scala.